# R Extraction of random uniform samples and create dataframes

Tags: r, list, dataframe, loops, random

I am new to R and am busy with an assignment that asks me to extract 10 samples of a 1000 random (but uniformly distributed) entries from a given dataset. I have found the sample.int function and it works to create a single dataframe result but I would like to create a list of the 10 random dataframes that I could use later to conduct a multiple linear regression model.

Also not sure if the sample.int gives me a runif selection of numbers

Help will be appreciated...as the below is all I have and cannot get off the ground

random.sample <- df[sample.int(nrow(df),1000),]

I was thinking, if I can create a loop to randomly select 1000 entries and create 10 dataframes, then I could use the list function and add them to it?

Comment: Check out the `replicate` function: `replicate(10, df[sample.int(nrow(df),1000),])`

Comment: Thanks will give it a shot now!